# How do I tell if a playlist is a music playlist in c#?

Tags: c#, playlist, wmplib

I've attached my code so far, my problem is all the playlists return "auto" or "wpl" for their type. (This is all using a WMPLib reference)

```
mediaplayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
// Init. Playlists
IWMPPlaylistCollection plcollection = mediaplayer.playlistCollection;
plarray = plcollection.getAll();
int i = 0, count = plarray.count;
string[] t = new string[count];

// Here is where I want to sort out non-music playlists
// And add them to the ListBox
for (i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
   t[i] = plarray.Item(i).getItemInfo("PlaylistType");

for (i = 0; i < count; i++ )
   PlaylistBox.Items.Add("" + plarray.Item(i).name);
```

Unrelated, but if you know how to attach the playlists as data instead of strings that would be helpful too :)

Comment: What do you expect each to return? Also, a playlist is not restricted to a single media type.

Comment: I'm making a music player, so I need to be sure that the playlists only have music in them. Is that not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can iterate through playlist items and if item's "*MediaType*" attribute equals "*audio*" deem this list as the one containing audio files. Smth like this:

```
private bool ListHasAudio(IWMPPlaylist playList)
{
    if (playList != null && playList.count > 0)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < playList.count; n++)
        {
            IWMPMedia media = playList.get_Item(n);
            string mediaType = media.getItemInfo("MediaType");
            if (mediaType != null && mediaType.Equals("audio", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

here's how you can use it:

```
var mediaplayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
// Init. Playlists
IWMPPlaylistCollection plcollection = mediaplayer.playlistCollection;
var plarray = plcollection.getAll();
// Load list box items
for (int i = 0; i < plarray.count; i++)
{
    IWMPPlaylist playList = plarray.Item(i);
    if (ListHasAudio(playList))
        PlaylistBox.Items.Add(playList.name);
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Did not think that I'd have to iterate the lists, but that makes sense. Thanks for the answer, I've updated your code to reflect my answer, but still good stuff!